# Writing a csv file from user input in django: each character appears on a new line

Tags: python, csv

In django, I have users who submit a form that contains a text area. In that text area, they paste information from a spreadsheet. This information will be tab-delimitated when they paste it. What I want to do is make a CSV file from this information (comma separated). Here is what I do:

```
input = request.POST['data']
path = '/path/to/file.csv'
in_txt = csv.reader(input, delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(path, 'w'))
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

However, if I use this information:

```
Header 1    Header 2    Header 3
Item 1  Item 1  Item 1
Item 2  Item 2  Item 2
```

Then it gets converted into:

```
H
e
a
d
e
r

1
,
H
e
a
d
e
r

2
,
H
e
a
d
e
r

3


I
t
e
m

1
,
I
t
e
m

1
,
I
t
e
m

1


I
t
e
m

2
,
I
t
e
m

2
,
I
t
e
m

2
```

So every character is shown on a new line. Why is this happening?

Using django 2.1 and python 3f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.reader` expects as its input an iterable of rows, but you are just passing in a string. Since a string is itself iterable, the reader interprets each character as a row.

The solution is to split your input into rows:

```
in_txt = csv.reader(input.split('\n'), delimiter = '\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

`writerows` takes an iterable of iterables. Basically, it takes a bunch of rows. Something like

```
 my_rows = [['Head1'], ['Head2'], ['Head3']
            ['r1c1'],  ['r1c2'],  ['r1c3'],
            ['r2c1'],  ['r2c2'],  ['r2c3']
           ]
 csv_writer.writerows(my_rows)
```

If you just have a single row, you should use `writerow` which takes an iterable:

```
my_headers = ['Head1', 'Head2', 'Head3']
my_row_1 = ['r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3']
```

---

In your case, you are bascially passing a string, which is an iterable (the string) of iterables (strings of length one). Thus it is putting each character in it's own row.

Comment: No, the problem is in the input, not the output.

Comment: But it does answer the question of "So every character is shown on a new line. Why is this happening?"